detect if ahk (autohotkey) script is running
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
DetectHiddenWindows, On
UH_Yourself: 
if WinExist("1UH_Yourself.ahk") { 
Menu, Curar_Menu, Color, 800000 Process, Close, 1UH_Yourself.ahk 
Process, Close, 1UH_Yourself.ahk
} else { 
Run, C:\Users\fabri\OneDrive\Desktop\Macros\Macros\1Cura\1UH_Yourself.ahk
 Menu, Curar_Menu, Color, 008000 } Return

How do I make the script identify ahk??

Try Process, Exist, I've used it and I'm pretty sure it will work in your case as well. Sorry if the script doesn't work properly, I'm a v2 user. 
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
DetectHiddenWindows, On
UH_Yourself: 
Process, Exist, "1UH_Yourself.ahk"
if ErrorLevel { 
Menu, Curar_Menu, Color, 800000 Process, Close, 1UH_Yourself.ahk 
Process, Close, 1UH_Yourself.ahk
} else { 
Run, C:\Users\fabri\OneDrive\Desktop\Macros\Macros\1Cura\1UH_Yourself.ahk
 Menu, Curar_Menu, Color, 008000 } Return

v2 version (I guess):-
SetTitleMatchMode 2
DetectHiddenWindows On
UH_Yourself:
if ProcessExist("1UH_Yourself.ahk") { 
Curar_Menu := Menu()
Curar_Menu.SetColor(800000)
ProcessClose "1UH_Yourself.ahk"
} else { 
Run "C:\Users\fabri\OneDrive\Desktop\Macros\Macros\1Cura\1UH_Yourself.ahk"
Curar_Menu.SetColor(008000)
}
Exit

Sorry if there are any mistakes in the v2 version, I tried my best to replicate what you did.
